# getting the non generic IValidationContext with the Type instead of T

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have an IValidator interface with a method `ValidateObject(object instance)`. I wish to implement this interface using FluentValidation as the underlying validation framework.  Using this issue (https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1961) as a guideline I've managed to get the non generic `FluentValidation.IValidator` but the `Validate` method requires `IValidationContext`.  I see no way to create an instance of the `IValidationContext` or get it without type T (which I don't know at the time of this interface).

Could it really be as simple as

```
    Type genericType = typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(instance.GetType());
    var validator = (FluentValidation.IValidator) _container.GetInstance(genericType);

    var context = new ValidationContext<object>(instance, new PropertyChain(), new DefaultValidatorSelector());

    var validationResult = validator.Validate(context);
```

Is there anyway to get the context based on Type (e.g. `instance.GetType()`) instead of T?